# Set double[] from float* in initialization list

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, double, memory-alignment

I have a class that looks roughly like this:

```
template<std::size_t dim>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(void const * const data);
private: 
    double vals[dim];
}
```

For the constructor, I know that `void* data` points to an array of `float` values (of dimension dim). Now I would like to initialize the `vals`-array (preferably) in the initialization list of that constructor.

To make matters worse, the floats pointed to do not necessarily have to be memory-aligned properly.

How could I do this efficiently?

---

### Edit 1

With respect to the discussion taking place below maybe let me state my design priorities first. This might help you to focus on that problems that matter most for me.

1. Cope with bad memory alignment
2. Get as few operations as possible in terms of performance.

Honestly, if we need the constructors body to get a fast algorithm working, this is fine for me as well. The focus is on raw power.

Comment: If `void* data` is known to be `float` then why is it not `float* data` ? Also, I don't think you can initialize an array from a pointer. You can mention, how you are using `Foo<>`; you may get better ideas/help.

Comment: I made it `void*` to ensure that I do not get into any mishap due to missing memory alignment. But maybe I am a bit to cationous there. 
For your second argument: Then I would gladly accept an efficient way to solve my problem within the constructors body...

Comment: Can you update your question with what kind of argument you want to pass to the `Foo()` ?

Comment: @Thilo - From where do you receive the `float` array, that you are worried about alignment problems?

Comment: The pointer directly points to a binary encoded data file that has a very compact format. There the datatypes are submitted in an order that alignment certainly is not ensured everytime. Especially, that format does not know anything about padding bytes. (I am not happy with this, but that format lies out of my scope, sadly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're afraid that passed pointer is not aligned to `float` boundary (for example, file mapping etc), then you can write something like

```
template<std::size_t dim>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(void const * const data)
    {
        float temp[dim];
        memcpy( &temp, data, dim * sizeof( float ) );
        std::copy( temp, temp + dim, vals );
    }
private: 
    double vals[dim];
}
```

Possibly an overzealous and not-so-portable solution:

```
template<std::size_t dim>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(void const * const data)
    {
        if( static_cast<long>( data ) % sizeof( float ) == 0 ) {
            const float *temp = data;
            std::copy( temp, temp + dim, vals );
        } else {
            float temp[dim];
            memcpy( &temp, data, dim * sizeof( float ) );
            std::copy( temp, temp + dim, vals );
        }
    }
private: 
    double vals[dim];
}
```

Initializing in the initializer list won't make your code faster, it's just a convenience when it's possible.

If you're strongly concerned about performance, I would wrap this `if` in a macro and only use `if` on the architectures, which require properly aligned access (x86 is not one, it's just slower on x86).

### Edit

Another solution proposed in the comments, thanks to 
[Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop). It focuses on reducing the temporary variable size.

```
double *dest = vals;
float tmp;
void const *first = data;
void const *last = data + dim * sizeof(float);
while( first != last ) {
    memcpy( &tmp, first, sizeof(float) );
    first += sizeof(float);
    *dest++ = tmp;
}
```

A bit of micro-benchmarking/disassebmlying is possibly needed.

Comment: Also thank you. Your first solution is what I had in mind at the beginning. However, I hoped beeing able to avoid that temporary variable. Looks like this still might be the way to go.

Comment: @Thilo, if you can't access these particular say 4 bytes as a single `float`, then you'll have to reconstruct this `float` an a properly aligned memory site. It's provable :)

Comment: Your logic surpasses me. That argument is to simple ;) Thank you for clearing some clouds for me.

Comment: @Thilo: you could avoid the `temp` variable being quite so large with something like `double *dest = &vals.begin(); float tmp; void const *first = data; void const *last = data + dim * sizeof(float); while (first != last) { memcpy(&tmp, first, sizeof(float)); first += sizeof(float); *dest++ = tmp; }`. Then look at the disassembly, it's at least possible that the compiler will eliminate the `memcpy` and do an unaligned load. If performance is critical then this still might lose compared with the bigger `memcpy`, of course.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code as you copied it, `&vals.begin()`? What nonsense!

Answer (score 0):

Because `float` is of different size than `double`, I think the only way is for a manual assignment from one array to the other.

Is it possible to change `vals` to be an array of `float`? This will allow you to copy the `data` array to it using `memcpy`. Because you don't gain precision in storing the `float`s in a `double` array, unless you change `vals` later to use the great precision of `double`, you don't gain anything from using `double`s.

Comment: Thanks for your input as well. The constructor shown is only one of many, while the other constructors do submit real double values. Thus, changing the members definition means a loss of accuracy I do not want to take.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hiding the type?

What is wrong with this :

```
template<std::size_t dim>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(float const * const data);
private: 
    double vals[dim]
}

template<std::size_t dim>
Foo< dim >::Foo(float const * const data) : vals()
{
  std::copy( data, data+dim, &vals[0] );
}
```

**EDIT**

If you switch to `std::vector`, you can initialize like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(float const * const dataBegin,float const * const dataEnd);
private: 
    std::vector< double > vals;
}

Foo::Foo(float const * const dataBegin,float const * const dataEnd) : vals( dataBegin, dataEnd )
{
}
```

Comment: OP has mentioned: `would like to initialize the vals-array (prefereably) in the initialization list`

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to initialize an array in the constructor initialization list... Is it possible at all?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am always unsure for which actions memory alginment is an issue. This especially holds for std::copy. If someone can confirm that I do not have to worry about this, this solution would make me fairly happy. (By the way: Does std::copy result in some kind of unnecessary overhead?)

Comment: @iammiling c++ (the current version) doesn't allow that.

Comment: Using vector negates the need in the template at all, obviously OP was trying to save on memory allocations, you suggest complete nonsense.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Your comment is a complete nonsense. The solution with a vector might be even better in some cases, because maybe he needs less memory then the solution with the c array assigns. btw where do you read he is trying to save memory allocations?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize an array in initializer list in current C++ standard. You can leverage the fact that you know the size in advance to use `std::vector`;

```
template<std::size_t dim>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(float const * const data) : vals(dim) // fix the vector size
  {
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<dim; i++)
      vals[i] = data[i];  // assignment
  }
private: 
  std::vector<double> vals;
};
```

I cannot argue that `vector<>` are as efficient as raw data; but they are well optimized and exception safe.

Comment: why talk about exception safety here? `double data[dims]` is at least equally exception safe.

Comment: Why use vector if we know the size of the array (it's the template argument)?

Comment: As the application behind is very performance critical, I would rather try to avoid std::vector. In my experience I have alway lost quite a bit of time with similar substitutions.

Comment: Furthermore, using the `data[i]`-syntax, I make myself almost certainly vulnerable to bad memory alignment.